# WampServer - Can't update or delete from MySQL (but I can create)

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, delete-row

I have a strange problem with WampServer that somehow won't allow me to edit or delete any data from the database (with a php file, I have fully control when loggin into the phpMyAdmin myself). I can create data, but neither update or delete data.

The problem occurred from one day to another.
Did someone have a problem like this or any guess on why this is happening?

I have tried looking for errors, but nothing is happening. I have tried looking for corrupted tables, but the error happens on every database, every table. The database user does have all the permissions needed.

Thanks,

** UPDATE **
To your who are asking for a code, sorry i didn't make it clear, but this is happening in every file and every code i tried, but here is a simple file i just created for your guys sake (that doesn't  work)

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "code", "webshop");

$mysqli->query("UPDATE webshops SET account_premium='1' WHERE id='1'");
?>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're trying to update it with?

Comment: Since it's not a solvable problem I suggest you simply close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by re installing the wampserver.
I think the problem was a fail in when i updated to MySQL version.

Comment: Was a weird one, glad you got it fixed :)